# row- vs. column-camera transformation matrices

Tags: opengl, math, unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity project in which I have to compute the screen coordinates of a world point "by hand". (So I can not use `Camera.WorldToScreen()`etc.)

At this point I am confused and don't even know what to google to clarify this.

I started with [this](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial13/tutorial13.html) tutorial and built a method that creates a camera transformation matrix like this

```
right_x,   right_y,   right_z,   0;
up_x,      up_y,      up_z,      0;
forward_x, forward_y, forward_z, 0;
0,         0,         0,         1;
```

This did not work until I used the negated forward-vector.

```
right_x,    right_y,    right_z,    0;
up_x,       up_y,       up_z,       0;
-forward_x, -forward_y, -forward_z, 0;
0,          0,          0,          1;
```

After this change it worked just fine.

Later I used [this tutorial](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html#modelview) for all the missing steps. The author creates a different matrix:

```
left_x, up_x, forward_x, 0;
left_y, up_y, forward_y, 0;
left_z, up_z, forward_z, 0;
0,      0,    0,         1;
```

All the other tutorials I found while trying to understand this also use this kind of matrix. They insert the vectors as columns instead of rows. Even though both tutorials are for openGL, only one of them works for me.

Can someone explain the difference to me?  Why this is the case?
And can someone explain why I have to invert my forward vector?

My guess is that both questions have to do with how openGL uses a right-handed, and Unity uses a left-handed coordinate-system. But in this case I don't understand, why are there two different OpenGL tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two tutorials you linked are described two different things.

1. The [olgdev.atspace.co.uk](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial13/tutorial13.html) tutorial is about the classical lookAt() camera or view matrix. This matrix describes the translation from world space to camera space.
2. The [songho.ca](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html#modelview) one describes transformation matrices in general. Let's ignore that what they label as "left" is actually supposed to be "right". They point they are trying to make here is that one can easily decode what a affine transformation matrix does by just looking at the columns: the x-Axis will be mapped to what the leftmost colum says, the y-Axis to the second column, z to the third, and the original will be translated to the fourth column.

The `right`, `up` and `forward` matrices  are defined in *world space* in case 1. However, in case of the second tutorial, they denote the resulting basis in *eye space*.
So conceptually, one is the inverse of each other. The matrix examples you gave ignore the translation part. What you are left with are just rotation matrices (all 3 vectors form an  orthonormal basis), so the resulting matrix is just orthogonal. And the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is just its transpose.

```
(x_eye)   (r_x_eye   u_x_eye   f_x_eye)       ( x_world )
(y_eye) = (r_y_eye   u_y_eye   f_y_eye)   *   ( y_world )
(z_eye)   (r_z_eye   u_z_eye   f_z_eye)       ( z_world )

          (r_x_world r_y_world r_z_world)     ( x_world )
        = (u_x_world u_y_world u_z_world) *   ( y_world )
          (f_x_world f_y_world f_z_world)     ( z_world )
```

Comment: I ignored the translation because I first subtract my camera position from my world point. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I still don't understand, why this only works with `- forward`. Could you explain this?

Comment: If this requires `-forward` or `+forward` actually depends on how you set up the projection matrix. The classic projection matrices in the GL (like the ones produced by the now deprectaed `glOrtho` or `glFrustum`/`gluPerspective` functions will define `-z_eye` as the viewing direction (but this is just a convention), so that your view matrix must transform the scene in such a way that your `forward` direction in world space is transformed to `-z_eye` (or, put otherwise, `-forward` must be transformed to `z_eye`)